# Wiquery DatePicker displays time, validation fails

Tags: java, validation, wicket, wiquery

I'm having problems with the Wiquery DatePicker in the following code in a Wicket page (using a CompundPropertyModel, the date property is of type java.util.Date):

```
DatePicker<Date> datePicker = new DatePicker<Date>("date"){
    @Override
    public boolean isVisible() {
        return selectedType.hasDate();
    }
};
datePicker.setDateFormat(DateUtil.DATE_PATTERN); // pattern is "dd.MM.yyyy"
form.add(datePicker);
```

The HTML this is bound to:

```
<input wicket:id="date" id="date"/>
```

The problem is that when editing existing data, the input field displays the time along with the date, and when submitting the form, validation fails because this does not fit the pattern.

How can I get the DatePicker to display the current value correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in the relatively obscure Wiquery DatePicker component. I've switched to  `org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar.DatePicker`, which does not have this problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the jquery native DatePicker [`setDateFormat`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat) method? It seems that the default dateFormat is `mm/dd/yy`. Is the default working properly?

Comment: @Xavi: I don't think the problem is on the JavaScript level, since it only appears when existing data is displayed, and I don't think the jQuery datepicker is involved at all until the user manipulates the field.

Comment: I've tried this in a WiQuery 1.2.4 and Wicket 1.4.7 quickstart. The initial value doesn't seem to get formatted according to `setDateFormat()`. It appears with the default `mm/dd/yy/` format. However, it isn't showing time.

Comment: It turns out the initial format was the one provided by the registered `IConverter` for `Date.class`. It's just behaving like an standard `TexField`, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Being the `DatePicker` component a `TextField`, why not use a custom `IConverter` in it to return only `dd.MM.yyyy` in its `convertToObject`?

I haven't been able to see browsing its [sources](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/source/browse/branches/1.1.x/src/main/java/org/odlabs/wiquery/ui/datepicker/DatePicker.java) any registered `IConverter` or other way to convert input, so this will probably be conflicting with whatever is formatting input in this component.

**UPDATE**

After debugging this in a quickstart using WiQuery 1.2.4 and Wicket 1.4.17, it shows that the initial value of the `DatePicker` (which is a `TextField`) is the standard conversion performed by `Component.getDefaultModelObjectAsString()`.

Since the `TextField` has a `IModel<Date>`, it will use whatever `IConverter` is registered for the `Date` class. In your case it might be using a custom `IConverter` that's formatting with the time. I'd try overriding `DatePicker`'s `getConverter()` and using a `SimpleDateFormat` that honours the format specified in `setDateFormat()`.

This issue gives a hint on that an `IConverter` should be specified along with the `DatePicker`: [Issue 168: Invalid (or uncommon) date format for NL in DatePicker](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/issues/detail?id=168)

You might also find this discussion on the Wicket users list useful: [DatePicker to pick a year](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/DatePicker-to-pick-a-year-td3063856.html). Julien Roche (one of the owners of the project) states there that `setDateFormat` only works on the client side with JQuery:

> I think you have to set the right converter on your wicket textfield (with 
>   the override of the method getConverter and with the class 
>   PatternDateConvert). The "dateFormat" option works only on the client side 
>   with jQuery.

Comment: Hopefully, this will be useful to people who've already decided on using Wiquery, but my project was already using the Wicket extensions DatePicker elsewhere, and I was using the Wiquery one accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

first take a look at https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/using-custom-converters.html

then you know that wicket convert you object to a text from that mechanic so..  all you have to do

Override newConverterLocator() method in Application class to provide custom ConverterLocator.

```
protected IConverterLocator newConverterLocator() {
    ConverterLocator converterLocator = new ConverterLocator();
    converterLocator.set(Date.class, new DateConverter());
    return converterLocator;
}
```

tip: watch out with java.sql.Date class converter